# bash script to convert epoch to standard in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, time, epoch

I work with several text files that use epoch, I would like a bash script that will scan a specific file for epoch and output another text document with it as standard time.

Comment: Mention details like: A sample of the epoch data you have. A sample of expected output. Shell version. Operating System. And most important, what do you mean by standard time?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux-BASH:

```
HUMAN_READABLE=$(echo $myTIMESTAMP | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}')
echo $HUMAN_READABLE
```